# Extract solution values from a matrix Linear Equation and plot solution line

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math, matrix

How do I extract the values of a matrix and create an equation with a for loop to plot a line? In an essence the picture below is what I am trying to do a simple linear equation:

[image: This is what I am trying to do]

With my data, I am using this code:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.matrix([[10,1],[45,1]])
B = np.matrix([[180],[140]])

A_inverse = np.linalg.inv(A)

X = A_inverse * B

X
```

Which outputs:

```
matrix([[  -1.14285714],
        [ 191.42857143]])
```

Ultimately I am trying to do is plot a line with the output of the matrix equation. Hopefully in some sort of a for loop, this is what I think the equation would look like:

lineplot = -1.14285714 * T + 191.42857143

I can make up some data, but how do I use it in the equation above where T could be the Random_Number ...? The `(m*x)+b` part below is just an idea what I need to modify and implement to hopefully make this work..

```
# Create a df with a date-time index with data every 6 hours
rng = pd.date_range('1/5/2018 00:00', periods=5, freq='6H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Random_Number':randint(1, 10, 5)}, index=rng)

lineplot = []
for T in Ts:
    lineplot.append((m*x)+b)
```

Comment: The core of your question seems to be *"How do I sweep over a range of x values/ the range of solutions"*, or as you put it: *"I can make up some data, but how do I use it in the equation above where T could be the Random_Number ...?"*

Comment: Thank you, Ill revise the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve with Pandas, but let's summarize the math related part - you are trying to solve equation: `y = ax + b` and you already found `a` and `b`. Now you need to find values of `y` for different values of `x`. Your random `T` is actually `x` from the equation. You can use some loop to calculate `y` for different values of `T` but your code will be rather slow. If you make use of dot product then you don't need any loops to calculate `y`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.matrix([[10,1],[45,1]])
B = np.matrix([[180],[140]])
A_inverse = np.linalg.inv(A)
X = A_inverse * B

T = np.arange(10) + (np.random.rand(10)-0.5) # some "random" T
line = np.vstack((T, np.ones(T.shape))).transpose().dot(X)

plt.plot(T, line, 'r*')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for showing me this.. Can you give me one additional tip? Ultimately I am trying to use this equation to calculate setpoint for a steam boiler system. The setpoint is based on outdoor air temp (the 10 & 45 above) where the boiler will maintain between 180 and 140 based on the outdoor temp. Its a simple linear reset... Im new to python and hoping not resort back to Excel, can you help me in what I need to do for building a separate pandas data frame of 'calculated setpoint' ? I have a few months of outdoor temp data and I am hoping to build a calculated setpoint (with the math) then plot

Comment: Hopefully that makes sense and the math that you helped me out with was part of the process! Thanks for your time